# VB.Net - How to display message if no records found?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to display a "No records found" message box, but I have no idea how to write the code. I have a search box and would like to create a message box if they records are found when the user searches.

```
Private Sub Search2ToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Search2ToolStripButton.Click
        Try
            Me.StaffTableAdapter.Search2(Me.Semester2DataSet.Staff, FirstNameToolStripTextBox.Text, SurnameToolStripTextBox.Text)
            'rather than crash the system, in the case of an error...
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            'A message box will appear telling the user of the error.
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Search2 is a query I created from my DataSet

```
SELECT StaffID, AddressID, FirstName, Surname, Occupation, [Mobile Number], [Contract Start], [Contract End] FROM Staff
WHERE (FirstName LIKE?) AND (Surname LIKE?)
```

Comment: Perhaps if you explain what the Search2 method does and what is its return value when you find something then it will be more easy to give you an answer that is not a guess

Comment: Its a query I created from my dataSet.

Comment: If you made `Search2` a function which returns the number of records found then it would be easier. However, I suspect that you are doing many things in the `Search2` method (e.g. read from the data *and* populate a control) and it would serve you well to refactor it into simpler methods which each do one thing.

Comment: I have a datasheet view which searches for records and when their are no records to display I want it to show that no records were found. How can I do this please.

Comment: "No records found" should not be an exception. You should be putting the results of the search into a datatable (or dataset), and then you can check to see if `yourDataTableName.Rows.Count()` is zero.

Comment: Can you help how I can achieve this.

Comment: if Semester2DataSet.Staff.Rows.count = 0 then . . . .